# Can I look up DNS A records through ldap?

Tags: windows, dns, active-directory, domain, ldap

I am trying to gather our domain controllers host A records remotely.
I am able to use `ldapsearch` to gather lots of info about the schema, computers, and users. But I cant seem to find where the A records are located.

I have been using "Active Directory Explorer" to build my baseDNs. As I look through it I do not see where host a records would be listed. Maybe its not possible to look them up.

BTW, our AD severs have zone transfers disabled so there is no way I can just dump them with a simple dig request.

Any recommendations? Note, not able to RDP to the system, must be done remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for AD-hosted zones is kept under `DC=DomainDnsZones,$BASE` as well as `DC=ForestDnsZones,$BASE` subtrees. Note that those are separate "partitions" so you *need* to specify them as the base DN for your search – a normal LDAP search won't descend into them automatically (instead, you might have seen "referral" results at the bottom your ldapsearch output).

The actual DNS record data is stored in binary format within the `dnsRecord` attributes.

All Windows DNS servers, whether AD DCs or not, also have their information accessible through RPC (the same that's used by RSAT's "DNS Server" console). You can use `samba-tool dns` to query the servers over RPC.

Comment: Ok `samba-tool` works much better than ldapsearch for what I needed. Here is one liner I used to combine all `Name` entries with their ip addresses:

`samba-tool dns query 10.10.10.10 company.local @ ALL --username 'COMPANY\adminperson' --password 'P4S5w0rd' | grep 'A: ' -B1 | sed 's/ //g;s/(.*)//g;s/,Records.*//g;s/AAAA://g;s/A://g' | awk '/^Name.*/{if(buf){print buf};buf=$1}/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/{buf=buf","$0}END{print buf}' | sed 's/Name=//g' | awk -F',' '{print"\""$2"\"," $3}' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed '1 i\\"hostname\",ip_addr' > ad_records.csv`